# Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x000002523CE84E48>>": "Balance.user" must be a "User" instance

Tags: python, django, wallet

I'm working on the Wallet Balance ASPECT of my django website. I want a situation where as soon as new user registers on the website his wallet balance is set to '0', But my code is throwing the above error. Kindly assist.

**VIEW**

```
@unauthenticated_user
def registration(request):

    form = CreateUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')

            group = Group.objects.get(name='customer')
            user.groups.add(group)
            Customer.objects.create(
                user=user,
                name=user.username,
            )

            instance = Balance(user=request.user, balance=10)
            instance.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Account was created for ' + username)

            return redirect('loginuser')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'account/registration.html', context)
```

**MODEL**

```
class Balance(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    balance = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user) if self.user else ''
```

**TRACEBACK**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ienovo\Domination\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\ienovo\Domination\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\ienovo\Domination\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ienovo\Domination\accounts\decorators.py", line 12, in wrapper_func
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ienovo\Domination\accounts\views.py", line 64, in registration
    instance = Balance(user=request.user, balance=10)
  File "C:\Users\ienovo\Domination\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 482, in __init__
    _setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
  File "C:\Users\ienovo\Domination\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 219, in __set__
    self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,

Exception Type: ValueError at /registration/
Exception Value: Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x000002523CE84E48>>": "Balance.user" must be a "User" instance.
```

Comment: The user is not logged in, so `request.User` is not a `User` object, and thus you can not assign it to your `Balance` boject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning the wrong `user` in your `registration()` view:

```
# in your views.py
instance = Balance(user=request.user, balance=10)
```

Your code above is referencing the user in your request object, which in this case would be the unauthenicated user `django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser`. If you want to reference the newly created user, you should use the `user` object that `CreateUserForm` just created:

```
instance = Balance(user=user, balance=10)
```

Comment: Thank you so much this "instance = Balance(user=user, balance=10)
" worked for me. I get the mistake. Once again thank you. You made my day.